# Getting highest count using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently developing a voting system. I wrote a query to get all votes but it only display all the vote getter, not the highest vote. What should I add in my query to execute what I need. Here's the code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   b.idnumber, b.candidate_name, semester,  
   (SELECT COUNT(rslt_ccandidateid) FROM rslt_mstr 
    WHERE rslt_ccandidateid = idnumber) AS 'numberOfVotes', 
   b.position, b.program, b.position_categ, b.party_name, 
   b.school, b.yearLevel, a.hierarchy           
FROM
   cddt_mstr b 
INNER JOIN 
   Position_mstr  a ON a.scposition_name = b.position 
WHERE 
   b.POSITION_CATEG = 'SUPREME COUNCIL CANDIDATES'  
   AND semester = '2ND SEMESTER A.Y. 2012-2013'  
ORDER BY 
   a.hierarchy, 'numberOfVotes' DESC
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data, desired results, and what our query is producing?

Comment: I just want to display the top vote getter in each position. With the query above, It just displays all the candidates with their votes ORDER by their respective position

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below might work.  I am assuming that rslt_ccandidateid IS NOT the vote value there is some other column, which I am calling [vote_column_name], that contains the vote value.  I am also assuming that the vote value is an integer column.   Lastly I am assuming you don't want the sum of all votes just the highest of all votes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.idnumber, b.candidate_name, semester, (
        SELECT MAX([vote_column_name])
        FROM rslt_mstr
        WHERE rslt_ccandidateid = idnumber
        GROUP BY rslt_ccandidateid
        ) AS 'numberOfVotes', b.position, b.program, b.position_categ, b.party_name, b.school, b.yearLevel, a.hierarchy
FROM cddt_mstr b
INNER JOIN Position_mstr a ON a.scposition_name = b.position
WHERE b.POSITION_CATEG = 'SUPREME COUNCIL CANDIDATES'
    AND semester = '2ND SEMESTER A.Y. 2012-2013'
ORDER BY a.hierarchy, 'numberOfVotes' DESC
```

Comment: It is not working. I get the vote through these codes "(select count(rslt_ccandidateid) from rslt_mstr where rslt_ccandidateid = idnumber) as 'numberOfVotes'" that is included in the code above